# Chain rule for already conditioned probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, chain-rule

I know that the chain rule says:

$P(A_1, A_2, A_3) = P(A_1 | A_2, A_3) P(A_2 | A_3) P(A_3)$

Is it then correct to say that

$P(A_1, A_2, A_3 | A_4) = P(A_1 | A_2, A_3, A_4) P(A_2 | A_3, A_4) P(A_3 | A_4)$

Or should I multiply by $P(A_4)$ at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the correct form using [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem): $P(A_1,A_2,A_3|A_4) = \dfrac{P(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4)}{P(A_4)}$. So you would need $P(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4)$ which is equal to $P(A_1 | A_2, A_3,A_4) P(A_2 | A_3,A_4) P(A_3|A_4) P(A_4)$.

This means that $P(A_1,A_2,A_3|A_4) = P(A_1 | A_2, A_3,A_4) P(A_2 | A_3,A_4) P(A_3|A_4)$.